# При попытке подключить базу данных к java выдаёт ошибку

Tags: java, sqlite

Имеется код следующего вида:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class conn {

    public static Connection conn;
    public static Statement statmt;
    public static ResultSet resSet;

    // --------ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЕ К БАЗЕ ДАННЫХ--------
    public static void Conn() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        conn = null;
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:TEST1.sdb");

        System.out.println("База Подключена!");
    }

    // --------Создание таблицы--------
    public static void CreateDB() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        statmt = conn.createStatement();
        statmt.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists 'users' ('id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 'name' text, 'phone' INT);");

        System.out.println("Таблица создана или уже существует.");
    }

    // --------Заполнение таблицы--------
    public static void WriteDB() throws SQLException {
        statmt.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('name', 'phone') VALUES ('Petya', 125453); ");
        statmt.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('name', 'phone') VALUES ('Vasya', 321789); ");
        statmt.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('name', 'phone') VALUES ('Masha', 456123); ");

        System.out.println("Таблица заполнена");
    }

    // -------- Вывод таблицы--------
    public static void ReadDB() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        resSet = statmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");

        while(resSet.next()) {
            int id = resSet.getInt("id");
            String  name = resSet.getString("name");
            String  phone = resSet.getString("phone");
            System.out.println( "ID = " + id );
            System.out.println( "name = " + name );
            System.out.println( "phone = " + phone );
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("Таблица выведена");
    }

    // --------Закрытие--------
    public static void CloseDB() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        conn.close();
        statmt.close();
        resSet.close();

        System.out.println("Соединения закрыты");
    }
}
```

Также имеется class с главным методом:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class db {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        conn.Conn();
        conn.CreateDB();
        conn.WriteDB();
        conn.ReadDB();
        conn.CloseDB();
    }
}
```

Но почему-то при вызове метода Conn в 12 строке вылетает ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at conn.Conn(conn.java:12)
at db.main(db.java:6)
```

В чём может быть причина? быть может не в той версии коннектора я использую версию sqllite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar и если так, то какую версию посоветуете? Кто-то вообще сталкивался с этой проблемой? Помогите пожалуйста я уже больше полгода не могу подключить базу к проекту. Хочется уже закрыть этот вопрос, а спросить не у кого.

Comment: Возможно вы не добавили или нет так добавили библиотеку в `classpath`. Покажите структуру файлов проекта, покажите как запускаете программу

Comment: Весьма и весьма Вам благодарен! Добавил jar-файл в папку с библиотеками и вауля! всё заработало! Огромное спасибо мой спаситель!

Answer (score 0):

```js
//
// IntelliJ IDEA Community 2019.2, jdk-12.0.1
// File\Project Structure\Libraries\Classes - сюда добавить путь
//                                            к sqlite-jdc-xxx.jar
//
// Main.java :

package com.samsoft;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        myclass.Conn();
        myclass.CreateTab();
        myclass.WriteTab();
        myclass.ReadTab();
        myclass.CloseDB();
    }
}

// myclass.java :

package com.samsoft;
import java.sql.*;

public class myclass {
    public static Connection conn;
    public static Statement st;
    public static ResultSet rs;

    //-------- Для подключения использован драйвер sqlite-jdbc-3.27.2.1.jar -------

    public static void Conn() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test1.db");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.println("Соединение с базой установлено.");
    }

    //-------- Создание таблицы --------
    public static void CreateTab() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        try {
            st = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users" +
                    "(id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
                    "name TEXT NOT NULL," +
                    "phone TEXT NOT NULL)";
            st.executeUpdate(sql);
            st.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(2);
        }
         System.out.println("Таблица создана (или уже существует).");
    }

    //-------- Заполнение таблицы --------
    public static void WriteTab() throws SQLException {
        try {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            st = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, name, phone) VALUES (1, 'Petya', 125453);";
            st.executeUpdate(sql);
            sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, name, phone) VALUES (2, 'Vasya', 321789);";
            st.executeUpdate(sql);
            sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, name, phone) VALUES (3, 'Masha', 456123);";
            st.executeUpdate(sql);
            st.close();
            conn.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(3);
        }
        System.out.println("Записи добавлены в таблицу.");
    }

    //-------- Чтение и печать таблицы --------
    public static void ReadTab() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        try {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            st = conn.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users;");
            while(rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                String phone = rs.getString("phone");
                System.out.println("id = " + id);
                System.out.println("name = " + name);
                System.out.println("phone = " + phone);
                System.out.println();
            }
            rs.close();
            st.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System .err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
            System .exit(4);
        }
        System .out.println("Чтение выполнено.");
    }

    // -------- Закрытие --------
    public static void CloseDB() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        conn.close();
        System.out.println("Соединение завершено.");
    }
}
```